# Insert multiple records in newly created column simultaneously in existing table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert

How to insert multiple values in a newly created column in existing table MySQL?

I am fairly new to SQL (beginner phase.)

I have an existing table named "members".

INSERT INTO members
(customer_id, join_date)
VALUES
('A', '2021-01-07'),
('B', '2021-01-09');

I then added a new column named "customer_name" :

alter table members
ADD customer_name varchar(25)

How to insert multiple values in the customer_name columns simultaneously?
I have tried:

update members
set customer_name = 'baby'
where customer_id = "A"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFAF0.png)

My question is how to update multiple rows at a time in a column of sql table?

Answer (score 0):

For example,

```
UPDATE members 
SET customer_name = CASE customer_id WHEN 'A' THEN 'Name 1'
                                     WHEN 'B' THEN 'Name 2'
                                     END
WHERE customer_id IN ('A', 'B');
```